# Remove Duplicate Chars without using an extra array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, char, duplicates

I'm currently working through Cracking the Coding Interview and I'm looking for some advice on what I can do to correct this algorithm. It appears to be working with some test cases, but it does not work with the test case ['a','a','a','b','b','b] as input. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Result expected = ['a','b']

Actual result = ['a']

```
/**
 * Removes duplicate chars
 * 
 * @param str
 */
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {

    if (str.length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
            if ((str[i] == str[j]) && (i != j)) {
                str[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug the code line by line if you don't understand why it's not working. It's an essential skill. Also you haven't shown what should be the result nor what you actually get as the wrong result.

Comment: Not knowing what the expected result is supposed to be, how can we know what is wrong? Replacing duplicate chars with `\0` seems unlikely to be correct, but .....

Comment: With your input of `['a','a','a','b','b','b']`, your method updates array to `['a','\0','\0','b','\0','\0']`. Is that what it's supposed to become? If yes, then your code works. If no, then what should it be?

Comment: Now that question shows expected and actual output, your question is a mess. Title says *"without using an extra array"*, but Java arrays are fixed size, so result cannot be `['a','b']` or `['a']` without creating a new shorter array. Please clarify, and when you do, perhaps that will also make it more clear in you own mind.

Comment: @Andreas Yes - it is suppose to be that. For some reason Eclipse is showing just 'a'...To clarify on using an extra array, I mean like declaring something like a StringBuilder object, then dumping non-duplicates into it. As a result, that will 'remove duplicates' and then we can return a String with the duplicates 'removed'. However, as char[] is mutable, I can remove items in the array without having to create another array/data structure.

Comment: @noobatrilla The *elements* of the array may be mutable, but the array *length* is not. You **cannot remove elements of an array**, you can only *replace* their values. If you intend your code to shorten the array, then you need to create a new array and return it, i.e. method cannot be `void`.

Comment: @Andreas Unless.. it just prints 'a' then goes to the next element and since it is a null character, the char[] is declared to be finished. Therefore, 'a' is only printed.

Comment: @noobatrilla If that is the case *(does the challenge say it is?)*, then perhaps the array should be `['a','b','\0','\0','\0','\0']` upon return, not `['a','\0','\0','b','\0','\0']` as it currently is. Doesn't that seem obvious, combining what you just said, with [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877891/remove-duplicate-chars-without-using-an-extra-array?noredirect=1#comment76734052_44877891) listing what your code is actually doing right now?

Comment: @Andreas this is the listed solution - doing replacements as you suggested. But I have no idea what it's actually doing..
 public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
  if (str == null)
   return;
  int len = str.length;
  if (len < 2)
   return;

  int tail = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
   int j;
   for (j = 0; j < tail; ++j) {
    if (str[i] == str[j])
     break;
   }
   if (j == tail) {
    str[tail] = str[i];
    ++tail;
   }
  }
  str[tail] = 0;
 }

Comment: @Andreas Ah ok - so somehow I will push the nulls all to the right

Comment: or just use Arrays.sort(str);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {

    if (str.length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(i + "-" + j + " = " + str[j]); //added this line
            if ((str[i] == str[j]) && (i != j)) {
                str[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I showing you this? This will show you what the removal process looks like as it goes along, and will help you better understand the problem. It actually works correctly.

I don't know how you got a result, because there is no print statement, *and* no `return` statement. But I did find a way to do it without using another `char` array(or any array for that matter). It simply reconstructs `str`. Check it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] chr = {'a','a','b','c','b','a','b','c'};
    System.out.println(removeDuplicates(chr));
}

public static char[] removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
    if (str.length < 2) {
        return null;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
            if ((str[i] == str[j]) && (i != j)) {
                str[j] = 0;
            }
            if (i == (str.length-1)) {
                str[i] = str[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

This example gives the output:

```
abc
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! So interestingly enough, I copied and pasted your provided example and my output was just 'a'. My IDE must be telling lies.

Comment: @noobatrilla Great! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the next (pseudo) code:

```
if (str.length < 2) {
      return;
 }

good = 1; //current number of unique items  

for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {

    success = 1;
    //scan only unique items
    for (int j = 0; j < good; j++) {
        if ((str[i] == str[j]) {
            success = 0;
            break;  
        }
    }

   //new unique - copy at the final place 
   if (success)  {
      s[good] = str[i];
      good++;   
   }
}
if (good<length)
  str[good] = 0;
```